# Why my MacBook Air terminal uses sh-3.2# instead of my username#?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

In my MacBook Air Terminal, I have the following prompt:

```
Zoos-MacBook-Air:~ zdm$
```

When I type `sudo su` and then enter my root password, I usually get the same prompt with the `#` sign as follows:

```
Zoos-MacBook-Air:~ zdm#
```

Recently I noticed that when I typed `sudo su` and then entered my root password, the prompt changed to:

```
sh-3.2#
```

How to change it back to usual?

Comment: Do you have the root user account enabled? Or have you had the root user account enabled and now have disabled the root user account?

Comment: I think it was never enabled.

Comment: Your root shell prompt probably wasn't `Zoos-MacBook-Air:~ zdm#` since when you are in a root shell, the username is always root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it changed, but you can override `sh-3.2#` or other default shell prompts by changing the `$PS1` variable. To do that, simply run the following command (including the space after the dollar sign):

```
export PS1='\h:\w \u\$ '
```

This will replace your shell prompt with `Zoos-MacBook-Air:~ root$`. However, this change is not persistent and will be gone when you `exit` or close the Terminal. You can make it persistent by editing root's .bash_profile file. Run the following command while you are in a root shell to modify that file:

```
echo 'export PS1='"'"'\h:\w \u\$ '"'" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PS1='"'"'\h:\w \u\$ '"'" >> ~/.profile
```

or

```
echo "export PS1='\\h:\\w \\u\\\$ '" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PS1='\\h:\\w \\u\\\$ '" >> ~/.profile
```

This will make the change persistent.

Tests were made on iOS 11 with root shell, but everything in this answer works on macOS as well.

Comment: `root`'s shell is `sh` not `bash` and `sh` does not read `.bash_profile`. This all centers around whether the shell is an interactive login shell or an interactive non-login shell and what config files are read.

Comment: @fd0 I edited the answer to include .profile

Comment: A bit closer to a correct answer. I suggest you read the section INVOCATION in the `bash` manual. Pay particular attention to the paragraph about `sh`.  When `su` is invoke as `sudo su` it will create a `interactive non-login shell` with `root`'s shell,`sh`. `sh` will not read any config files unless you set a file in the `ENV`  environment variable. Now, this get a bit complicated declaring variables and writing a new configuration file...etc. Simply, instead of using `sudo `su` , use `sudo su -l` .

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su` prompts `sh-3.2#` in my Mac too, unlike linux kernels.
It’s `sudo -i` that gets you to the `blah-blah-Air:~ root#`.

When you use `ls` in each however, you’ll notice the `sh-3.2#` lists much more directories and files than your `:~ root#`.

Try `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` if you want the `:~ root#`.

I heard, `-s` is to "keep environment”, `-i` is to have a “new login shell”.
Get more info about sudo commands by typing `man sudo` in your terminal.

Comment: The man page explains the various options for sudo, it usually is the better reference than hearsay :-)

Comment: I heard I already referenced man page....